# Bundle Missing Provisioning Profile in Xcode upload to App Store/Testflight

Tags: xcode, testflight, mac-catalyst

I have been able to upload the iOS version of my app to the App Store.
But when I tried uploading the MacOS version (Catalyst) I keep getting an error

> WARNING ITMS-90889: ""Cannot be used with TestFlight because the bundle at “TradeFlags.app” is missing a provisioning profile. Main bundles are expected to have provisioning profiles in order to be eligible for TestFlight.""

I see on other posts one needs to re-download the provisioning profiles, which I did.
Checking in Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Manage Certificates, I see all the new versions been added when I generated them a new.

[image: Preferences-Xcode-ManageCerts]

But it still gives the same error as above when I try to resubmit the build to the App Store.

I am out of wits on what to do next. Can anyone suggest what to do next?

Comment: Same here. Probably a new "invention" of Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Xcode 12 lacks the ability to correctly submit Mac Catalyst apps using automatic provisioning.

Even though this prevents the catalyst app from using TestFlight it is still able to be submitted for review.

However, I was able to get rid of this warning by creating a Mac Catalyst provisioning file and selecting Manual provisioning when submitting the app.

[image]

Comment: thanks will try that. but i was able to submit the app before with automatic selected. this was just ment to be an update of the privacy link. nothing changed in the code so its likely an apple side change. updating to xcode 13 beta breaks my whole app.